# Dynamic currency in MVC 5 from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My current model to store a specific vendors currency is show below where the VendorCurrency value will be like "en-US" or "en-CA" and so forth.

Currently I am using the  tag in the Web.Config which sets the default currency globally but the requirement to make the site multi-currency has come about.

Is there a simple way to use the model to determine which currency to use on the fly in Views?

Vendor:

```
public string VendorID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Name = "Vendor Name")]
public string VendorName { get; set; }

[StringLength(50)]
public string VendorCurrency { get; set; }
```

Invoice:

```
public string Invoice_Number { get; set; }

public int VendorID {get;set;}

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal? Invoice_Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you wanting this for display only, or are you also wanting to edit the value in the users culture as well (in which case you would need to a custom ModelBinder and you would need to configure the `$.validator` if you also want client side validation)

Comment: This is for display only. Users wont be able to edit.

Comment: If that is the case, one solution would be to have a (say) `string CurrencyFormat` property which you could set in the GET method based on the users culture - for example it might be "$#.00" for `en-US` and then in the view use `@Model.Invoice_Amount.ToString(Model.CurrencyFormat)`.

Comment: Thanks! I sort of combined your answer and Cory's below to create an extension method to determine the Culture detected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in your controller, prior to returning the view:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Us");
```

**Huge Caveat:**

This setting will last *beyond* your view execution and action execution. It will bleed into future action executions.

Also, a lot of coders do not properly specify cultures when parsing/printing numbers and if you have code like that, setting `CurrentCulture` like this will subtly wreak havoc on it.